# Manually adding a mesh to Drake scene graph as anchored geometry

Tags: drake

I have a .obj mesh on my file system and I'd like it to be added to my scene graph so that other systems in my diagram can interact with it. Here is a little snippet that I'm using, which doesn't work.

```
def add_mesh_to_scene_graph(name, path, scene_graph):
    mesh = Mesh(path)
    id = scene_graph.RegisterSource()
    geometry = GeometryInstance(RigidTransform(), mesh, name)
    geometry.set_illustration_properties(IllustrationProperties())
    geometry.set_perception_properties(PerceptionProperties())
    geometry.set_proximity_properties(ProximityProperties())
    scene_graph.RegisterGeometry(id, scene_graph.world_frame_id(), geometry)
```

When viewing the scene with Meshcat, I don't see the object show up in the scene at all. I'm guessing it's because I didn't configure the properties correctly, but I didn't find any documentation on how to properly configure the illustration/perception/proximity properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe easiest way to add some visualization properties is to use [`MakePhongIllustrationProperties`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/namespacedrake_1_1geometry.html#aa70628317c9ed8d19606fee0d13643a5):

```
geometry.set_illustration_properties(
        MakePhongIllustrationProperties([0, 0, 1, opacity])
    )
```

where the four numbers are rgba.

Comment: Thanks @RussTedrake. If I have an associated mtl file, is there a way to add that into the illustration properties? Also, are there similar helper functions to construct PerceptionProperties and ProximityProperties? These property objects themselves don't seem to have any client facing methods.

Answer (score 1):

To your questions under Russ's answer:

As far as I know, you don't need to do anything special to use mtl files associated with obj files to use it for illustration. It is done automatically.

See the "Appearance of OBJ files" section in https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_drake_visualizer.html (This is for DrakeVisualizer, but the same holds for MeshcatVisualizer).

See [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/8ad8990760de9666d6737c7272666c8886ebffe8/geometry/test/quad_cube.obj#L1) for an example obj file and [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/8ad8990760de9666d6737c7272666c8886ebffe8/geometry/test/quad_cube.mtl#L1) for the associated mtl file.

For proximity properties, see the [AddContactMaterial()](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/namespacedrake_1_1geometry.html#a06f08c367a0ef97e7fc397a8a44d49d8) sugar. There are other sugars for ProximityProperties on the same page.

There's no perception properties sugar that I'm aware of. It's likely that you'll have to add properties by hand via [AddProperty()](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_geometry_properties.html#a5c36bb4c5566a8316bc8b52601e49d27).

Comment: Thanks @XuchenHan. Is there documentation on what sort of strings and values are valid perception properties for interfacing with Drake's simulated RGB camera for instance?

Comment: AFAIK, there's not a single place that documents all the useful perception properties. There's assigning [render label](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1render_1_1_render_engine.html) and [assigning accepting render](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_scene_graph.html#a25dc47d81e495aad7dee6d2932dcd655). I believe the phong property Russ mentioned above is also used in render engines.